# i18n for Angular 6 using angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I've been reading Angular documentation for i18n using the ng tool `xi18n`. It looks like an impressive tool but I didn't get the following line.

> When you internationalize with the AOT compiler, you must pre-build a
>   separate application package for each language and serve the
>   appropriate package based on either server-side language detection or
>   url parameters.

does it mean I need to build 100 apps & do the serve depending on the detection I do on server side?

Question is,

> > Is it even possible in production scenarios?

Comment: http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2017/01/15/i18n-angular-cli-aot/

Comment: Yes you build one app for every language and need to serve the correct app depending on the language setting. This is because during the compiling process the app gets translated. Using aot means it is pre compiled consequently you need a pre compiled version for every language. Alternatively you can use libraries such as : https://github.com/ngx-translate/core which uses an external json and a pipe to translate keys into readable content.

Comment: @Chellappan please add some description with the link, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have an app on the prod in 2 languages fr and en, you have to build your app for each language and with different base url, in my case i've added in my package.json

```
 "scripts": {
     ...
     "build-i18n:fr": "ng build --output-path=dist/fr --aot -prod --bh /fr/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=fr",
     "build-i18n:en": "ng build --output-path=dist/en --aot -prod --bh /en/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en",
     "build-i18n:default": "ng build --output-path=dist/en --aot -prod --bh /en/",
     "build-i18n": "npm run build-i18n:default && npm run build-i18n:fr"
  },
```

after that you have to add your web server config to serve these 2 apps, each one in subdirectory:

```
   https://www.yourapp.com/en/
   https://www.yourapp.com/fr/
```

here is an example for IIS

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^../index\.html$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(..)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/index.html" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 3">
                <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" pattern="^fr" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/fr/" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 5">
                <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" pattern="^es" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/en/" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

you have to add some code to manage navigation between the 2 apps in your language switch component. you get the current url and then redirect

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" *ngIf="!isDev">
      <li  *ngFor="let language of languages;let i=index" >
           <a id="TopNavLinkLanguageName{{ i}}"  href="/{{language.lang}}/#{{getCurrentRoute()}}"  (click)="changeLanguage(language.lang)">
                        <img [src]="..." alt="flg" />
            </a>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

your ts file

```
getCurrentRoute() {
    return this.router.url;
}
changeLanguage(lang: string) {
    const langs = ['en', 'fr'];
    this.languages = this.allLanguages.filter((language) => {
        return language.lang !== lang;
    });
    this.curentLanguage = this.allLanguages[langs.indexOf(lang)].name
    localStorage.setItem('Language', lang);
    if (isDevMode()) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to provide language support for at least 5 languages with two apps. So, I need to build (5*2 = 10) different apps?